# modify how emacs auto-fill function works

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm trying to edit documents (MultiMarkdown), that will do an auto-fill on paragraphs that are not indented 4 spaces, and will NOT do an auto-fill on paragraphs that ARE indented 4 spaces.

Where should I start to look to figure out how to code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need `fill-paragraph`, `if`, probably `progn`, probably `string=`, `save-excursion`, `forward-paragraph`, `backward-paragraph` and perhaps a few more.  All of these can be read up if you do `M-x describe-function` and supply it the name.

As for the how, it is in your question.  If the paragraph begins with 4 blank space letters, `fill-paragraph`.

Does that answer?  Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I start to look to figure
>   out how to code this?

I think this is too general a question to answer. We don't know anything about your background in programming. Do you know Lisp? Do you know elisp? How well do you know Emacs? Do you know about [`advice`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions)? etc.

Programming in Emacs is well documented ([introduction](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/index.html) and [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html)). I suggest you start playing around with the `fill-` functions - when you run into more concrete problems with that, I'm sure it will be easier for people to help you out.